# Will using CSS within <noscript> to hide article content affect SEO?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, seo-audit, noscript

We have a large site with a half million articles in it that uses a javascript-powered paywall to block article body content for users who do not have an active subscription. It has become a problem that people are encouraging the community on social media to disable javascript in order to circumvent this paywall.  As a solution, we have implemented a `<noscript>` tag in all article pages that displays a message encouraging users to enable javascript that includes CSS that hides the body content of the article.

In my research, I found a decent amount of seemingly contradictory statements related to usage of the `<noscript>` for SEO, and some information was very dated (sometimes 10 or 15 years old). Could this practice of hiding the body content of the article and providing an additional message telling the user they are required to enable javascript before they can read the article content result in negative SEO?

Comment: Are you using Google's flexible sampling policy for paywall content?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I want to assume so since our paywall is powered by a somewhat widely used third party service.

Comment: You should make sure.  [Here are Google's flexible sampling guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/flexible-sampling) and [here are the instructions for the structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/paywalled-content) that you are required to put in your pages.  Third party services can usually be configured in a variety of ways, not all of which will be compliant.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Let's assume that I have all the guidelines met. Do you think that's good enough and I don't have to worry past that point?